# Application crashing with on file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift Xcode 12, iOS 14, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker, ios14

The app I'm currently building works perfectly fine on iOS 13 but crashes most of the times when I click on picker view that is shown using ZStack with the error.

**Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444**

The crash occurs most of the times and I am unable to find the problem.

Has anyone encountered the same issue or could anyone tell me whats causing this only in iOS 14?
Thanks

While replicating the similar code in a demo app, it seems to run fine most of the times and crashes rarely. Below is the code for the demo app.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showPicker = false
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    @State var pickerValues: [String] = []
    @State var selectedValue = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            VStack() {
                if !pickerValues.isEmpty {
                    Text(selectedValue)
                        .padding()
                }
                Button {
                    self.pickerValues = [
                        "First Element",
                        "Second Element",
                        "Third Element",
                        "Fourth Element",
                        "Fifth Element",
                        "Sixth Element",
                        "Seventh Element"
                    ]
                    self.showPicker.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Picker")
                }

            }

            if showPicker {
                AppPickerView(title: "Picker", data: self.pickerValues, selectedData: self.$selectedValue, show: self.$showPicker)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AppPickerView: View {
    var title: String
    var data: [String]
    @Binding var selectedData: String
    @Binding var show: Bool
    @State var showAnimation: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.init(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3980798856))
            VStack() {
                Text(title).font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding()
                picker.animation(nil)
                cancelAndSelect.animation(nil)
            }
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .padding()
                .transition(.opacity)
                .offset(x: 0, y: showAnimation ? 0 : 50)
                .opacity(showAnimation ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.25))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }.onAppear() {
                self.showAnimation = true
        }

    }

    var picker: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedData, label: Text(""),
            content: {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { (string: String) in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }).pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(height: 150)
    }

    var datePicker: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedData, label: Text(""),
            content: {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { (string: String) in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }).pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(height: 150)
    }

    var cancelAndSelect: some View {
        HStack() {
            Button(action: {
                self.hideAppPicker()
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }.buttonStyle(BackButtonStyle())

            Button(action: {
                self.hideAppPicker()
                print(self.selectedData)
            }) {
                Text("Ok")
            }.buttonStyle(ForwardButtonStyle())
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
            .padding(.all, 10)
    }

    func hideAppPicker() {
        self.showAnimation = false
        self.show.toggle()
    }

    func selectInitalData() {
        if let firstElement = self.data.first, self.selectedData.isEmpty {
            self.selectedData = firstElement
        }
    }
}
struct BackButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(Color.secondary)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(color: Color.secondary.opacity(0.4), radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)

    }
}

struct ForwardButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.primary)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(color: Color.primary.opacity(0.4), radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
    }
}

struct SecondaryButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
            .overlay(Capsule().stroke(Color.primary, lineWidth: 1))
            .shadow(color: Color.secondary.opacity(0.4), radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the SAME problem.  Mine happens to my secondary picker, that replaces the primary picker (which works correctly).   The ForEach works WITHOUT the picker.  Adding the picker causes the problem.   I'll file a bug report if I can't find a solution.